# Scala mllib 2.2.0 k means. Number of runs

Tags: k-means, scala

As per the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-clustering.html#k-means), the `runs` parameter does nothing.
I have looked at the actual Scala code for k means and it appears that the `train` method only does one start. There is no way to change this.

**QUESTION:**
Am I correct that if I want 5 starts I need to write my own code that calls `train` 5 times (or until some criteria has been met)?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. It used to control making multiple starts at once but for various reasons this didn't work well, and was deprecated / made a no-op. I removed it for Spark 3.0.